# New Random entries and Shifting

Tags: matlab

please any one help me to shift 1 element towards right in a loop of 32 elements and on the first entry of an array,everytime it gets new rand number either +1,-1 and shifts the remaining elements towards right.
i am doing in this way but it's not working properly

```
 clc
    clear all    
    near_input=zeros(1,32);     %vector of 32 elements with all zeros
        y=2*round(rand(1,1))-1;     % random bernoulli sequence (+1,-1)
        z=[y near_input(1:end-1)];
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't just insert the elements directly? Why do you want the shift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you insert all the number at once, avoiding the shifting. You can do this simply like this:

```
z = 1-2*round(rand(1,32))
```

The inputs to `rand` is the number of rows and columns. Therefore, `rand(1,32)` is the same as putting 32 `rand(1,1)` next to each other. And for the record, `rand(1,1) == rand()`.

However, if you *really have* to do it your way, you need to do some changes. The following works (but is really bad code).

```
near_input = zeros(1,32);
for ii = 1:numel(near_input)
   y = 2*round(rand(1,1))-1;
   near_input = [y, near_input(1:end-1)]
end
% z = near_input;
```

Comment: @ Robert  Thx actually it's the requirement of my code to generate random numbers bit by bit and shift it to the right every time

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the entire sequence like this:

```
y = sign(2*(rand(1, 32) - 0.5)); % 1x32 array of +-1's
```

Or, if you insist on creating them one-by-one with 'push-right' (or more accurately 'concat-left'):

```
y = [];
for unused = 1:32
    y = [sign(rand() - 0.5), y];
end
```

Which has the disadvantage of changing `y`'s size in a loop (a real performance hit if you use large arrays). A better approach would be to pre-allocate `y`, and assign by index:

```
y = zeros(1, 32);
for index = 32:-1:1
    y(index) = sign(rand() - 0.5);
end
```

Running the index from 32 down to 1, assigns the values into `y` from right to left as you put it.